# Get "out" of react-router (make a new server request on a redirect)

Tags: reactjs, redirect, react-router

I'm trying to make a simple website (shared hosting on an Apache server) with a static part on root (upload of the build created by react-build) and a wordpress blog on /blog.

The problem is that I can access the blog when directly typing mysite/blog in the url bar, but when I try to redirect from my react page, I cannot "escape" the React-Router and mysite/blog falls into my 404 route case. **I would like to have a `<Link>` in my react homepage that sends me to my blog.**

I think I have to make an external redirection so the server is consulted again to serve the wordpress homepage, but don't seem to find how.

So far, I've tried:

- Using `<a>` tag instead of `<Link>` (it seems to get stuck in a loop)
- Using a `<Redirect from="/blog/" to="/blog/" />`
- Getting a .htaccess to redirect "/blog/" to "/blog/" with a 301 redirection

My app :

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <HttpsRedirect>
      <Router>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Portfolio} />
            <Route component = {FourOhFour}/>
          </Switch>
        </Router>
        </HttpsRedirect>
    );
  }
}
```

My .htaccess: (this is to redirect every external request to my index.html file generated by react, otherwise the React-Router wouldnt catch mysite/foo - it does not conflict with mysite/blog however)

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]
```

If someone has suggestions to make, it would be greatly appreciated !